# Why should I not disclose my salary?

Tags: salary, employment, privacy

I'm not looking to blurt out or brag about my salary in social media or anything.

I'm apparently making an article about how to get a raise and I am planning to disclose the exact raise (not salary) that I got.

Of course, the usual problem within friends is envy and in general, that you might be taken advantage of, knowing you gain X amount of money.

But other than that, is there anything else I'm not seeing as a disadvantage in disclosing my salary/raise?

Comment: Is there anything in your employment contract about disclosing your salary? While it may not happen often, some places may have confidentiality clauses that this could be a violation.

Comment: I'll check the contract now @JBKing.

Comment: @JBKing, here's the line in the contract : *4.4 You must not discuss your hourly rate of pay with anyone while you are engaged by ---- under this Agreement.* I guess I can't disclose my salary in terms of the contract, but I guess a raise, especially if it's a percentage only, is safe?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the contract also says something about not sharing the contents of the contract as well, if not covered by your non disclosure clause. If you want to be extremely safe, ask your supervisor.

Answer (score 5):

Future job offers can go up or down depending on your disclosure, people can interpret it as bragging... maybe you could just use a percentage?

Comment: The percentage part is a really good suggestion for the article so +1 for that

Comment: Paste me a link in here when you finish it! Interested in reading the result :-)

Answer (score 2):

Miscreants might be better able, or more motivated, to target a crime, scam, or lawsuit at you if they have an idea of your income or wealth, especially if it's above average. Salespeople for big-ticket items might have a negotiating advantage if they have a data point on what you can afford to pay. And you might receive annoying solicitations from stockbrokers and charities who would love to target people in a known income bracket.

Basically, the reasons you would try to keep lottery winnings or an inheritance discreet.

Answer (score -1):

Just blurt it out.  With friends you can always blurt it out.  I have had friends hang up on me in disgust after realizing how they are getting shafted.  But we are still friends.  Better friends, now that they got their 40% increase...  :P

Here is the thing.  Salary secrecy is a Commercial Industrial Complex scam.  This is how they keep us in the dark about how much we are worth.  This is how they keep wages artificially low, so that the Man can have another private jet.

How they do it is by creating this phony social construct where it is somehow considered rude to talk money with your peers.

Whether the talk of money is considered bragging entirely depends on one's point of view.  If you aren't bragging, your friends / peers won't perceive it as bragging.

And salary discussions inevitably leads to useful information exchange.  Like how the heck are you making so much.  OR why the hell are you making so little?

And if you are worried about your employment contract about disclosing your salary...  Just lie.  It is easy!

If you making $60,543.55 a year.  Tell people you are making 61,000 or 60,000.  I am 100% certain no employment contract ever says you can't lie about your salary.  Luckily for us, most of us make a hard to remember sum, so it really shouldn't be too difficult to lie.

As for job searches, they almost always ask you what you are currently making (assuming you are currently employed).  You should always lie.  Here is the thing.  If they didn't plan to low ball you with what you are currently making, they wouldn't even be asking the question.

Does a bad faith question deserve a good faith answer?